# Kibana KQL Visualisation Filter - Exclude one value of list field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a elastic index with an "origin" field. This field can have either one or two strings/keywords in a list/array format like this:

```
"origin": [
  "live"
],
```

or

```
"origin": [
  "live",
  "upload"
],
```

In Kibana I want to create a visualization that splits me the chart in

- only "live"
- only "upload" or
- both

[image: Kibana Screenshot]

But if I write a filter command like

```
origin.keyword : "live"
```

it obviously it true if the list contains only "live" or both like ["live", "upload"].

**How do I have to write this KQL filter to only list documents where "origin" only contains the value "live" in the list?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "filter" aggregation for that.

[image]

Will give you graphs like this:
[image]

If you need the precise use case describe in your comment

[image]

Filters a written in kql, so don't hesitate to read the doc to construct your own cases
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.9/kuery-query.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but this is not my case. In you example you have a doc with either 404 or 200. But I have docs with a field containing a list like [404, 200].

Comment: I swear I tried this and it did not work. It looked like it evaluated it per item. 
But yes this works, thanks:
`origin.keyword : "live"  and not origin.keyword : "upload" `

Comment: syntax can be difficult to handle in kibana/elastic as their is small differences everywhere depending on the context you execute it